# .net FileSystemWatcher does not pick up moved folders

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystemwatcher

I have found plenty of discussions regarding moved **files** (which I have no problems with), but not any specific to moved **folders** (hence this post).

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` instantiated as follows:

```
  var fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\mypath");
  fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
  fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                               | NotifyFilters.FileName
                               | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                               | NotifyFilters.Size;
   fileWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
   fileWatcher.Created += OnChanged;
   fileWatcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
   fileWatcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
   fileWatcher.Error += WatcherOnError;
   fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

No matter what I do with files, I get the events raised as expected, however if I **drag** (move) in a folder (even with files in it) to the watched folder, none of the events are raised at all.

I am running on Windows 10 (not sure if other versions of win behave the same way).

Does anyone know how to get a notification for a **folder move**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly excluding directory changes by not including `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName` in your `NotifyFilter`.

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx) to the documentation, but it's only correct by implication :-) I confirmed it by just using your code without and then with the extra flag.

Comment: Thanks for that. Adding that flag I now get the notifications for folder moves (completely missed seeing that one when looking through the list of flags).

Answer (score 1):

Strange, this works for me:

```
void Main()
{
    FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"c:\Temp\");
    fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    while (true) { }
}

void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the above worked since there are no NotifyFilters set, so it must default to all of them, including the `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName` as mentioned below.